# 2 correlated variables , 2 conditions and 3 groups: what analysis?

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures

In a design with two correlated dependent variable measures with similar range and variance, two within subject conditions and three diferent participant groups each tested at a diferent time point.  Which would be the most apropriate statistical analysis?  I thought about a repeated measures anova, but I am not sure whether to run separate analysises or how to analyse the two correlated variables? I am interested in possible interactions between factors and also whether the factors predominantly effect just one or both of the variables.  I am using SPSS 18, for the analysis.